# I cannot link freeglut to code::blocks on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, c++, opengl, code-blocks

Following are my related includes:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

And the following are added to my `Settings->Linker Settings->Link Libraries`

`GL
GLEW
GLU
SDL2`

I was working on Windows and it was easy to link libraries, but here I cannot find a `lib` folder for freeglut. Please give me a boost.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one thing I didn't try and it was adding the flag

`-lglut`

I kept trying it with lfreeglut and variants. This is the answer.